# Setup Apache Proxy Rules using Query Parameter

Tags: regex, apache, http, http-proxy, proxypass

How can I setup apache proxy to proxy request based on query parameters?

In below configuration, I want apply only url1 rules without affecting other rules.

```
ProxyPassMatch     ^/url1/wsdl       http:///url2/wsdl$1 disablereuse=on
ProxyPassMatch     ^/url1/ws         http:///url3/ws$1 disablereuse=on
ProxyPassMatch     ^/url1/ws?wsdl    http:///url4/wsdl$1 disablereuse=on
ProxyPassMatch     ^/url1/ws?xsd=1   http:///url5/xsd$1 disablereuse=on
ProxyPassMatch     ^/url6(.*)        http:///url7$1 disablereuse=on
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/776694/apache-proxypass-pass-requested-url-as-get-parameter-to-destination-url

Comment: I have another rules in same conf. file, I don't want to apply this RewriteCond on all rules.